# Ansible list variable reference

Tags: list, variables, reference, ansible

I have a list of variables, let's say

```
servers:  
 - server1    
 - server2
```

And I have folders on my hosts:

```
/tmp/server1   
/tmp/server2
```

Now I would like to create files in those folders. I need to reference to all variables in the list separately. If I reference in the task to `{{ servers }}` it creates folder `/tmp/[server1, server2]`. When I do `{{ server[0] }}` it creates a file in `server1` folder which is good, but I need to reference to all variables in the list separately not all at once. I think the answer will be something like `{{ server[*] }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Loops in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

Your task will look like this:

```
- file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ item }}/myfile"
    state: touch
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
```

The above will create empty files (or update their datetime, just like `touch` command) `/tmp/server1/myfile`, `/tmp/server2/myfile` on all target servers.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I add a line into file in those directories? Lets assume I created files in previous task and now I would like to insert configuration. 
lineinfile: path=/tmp/{{ item }}/myfile line={{ item }}
with_items:
   - #my configration here.
It seems like I need to use 2 times {{ item }} variable with different values.

Comment: Use `template` module.